# React Native Gifted Chat appends messages two times when socket.io updates new message

Tags: react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

This is my first question on StackOverflow. 
Please help me with the real-time chat application in react native using react-native-gifted-chat and socket.io
Some messages are rendered even which are not present twice in the "messages" state.

[chat on top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUbkn.png)

[same messages in middle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nIiN.png)

[again same messages in last of the scroll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQ0tI.png)

[gifted chat code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmv4V.png)

[This is the function which is called when a new message comes up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BO9Dv.png)

Comment: Could you add the code that you use to show the chat?

Comment: @MaartenDev, please check it out.